# Excel Slicer doubles graph value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a graph containing costs over time and i have 2 slicers.
one with groups and the other one with section.

When I select a section like ART, it is also present in the slicer for group such as,

Section------Group

ART ----- >--/ART

ARX------- /ARTT

ARC------- /ARTX

The problem with this is that if I don't <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click in group slicer at ART. This will show at my graph values at the double. So if the correct answer is 250k for q1 for section ART, it will be shown as 500K if I don't deselect in group.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? I still need have section so I can't remove it from source data.

Comment: How are you using VBA? You might want to include the code.

Comment: Sorry for the misshaps. i dont use VBA for this it is simply 2 slicer from pivot table.